# How to print the sorted array in word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a two Input data of Year and Name in separate two arrays. I need to sort both the array values first i need to sort it chronologically(Year) and then if year information repeats it will sort the Array Alphabetically.

As for as I complete the sorting for both year and then name. Using `Wordbasic.sortarray` command

**Input**: (Before sorting)

```
SDF 1997
ELS 1986
PJK 1983
WKL 1995
EFD 1986
```

**Output**: (After sorting)

```
PJK 1983
EFD 1986
ELS 1986
WKL 1995
SDF 1997
```

If I print it in word it printed like this:

```
PJK 1983, ELS 1986, EFD 1986, WKL 1995, SDF 1997.
```

Here is my code for Printing the data. Would anyone please look into this and guide me where did i made mistake?

```
WordBasic.sortarray SortyearArray()
```

**Code**:

```
Dim I As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim K As Integer
Dim N As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer
COUNTER1 = 1

i1 = 1
J1 = 5

For I = 0 To UBound(SortyearArray())
    Counter = 1
    For J = I + 1 To UBound(SortyearArray())
        If SortyearArray(I) = SortyearArray(J) Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
            MsgBox (Counter)
        End If
        COUNTER1 = Counter + COUNTER1
    Next J
    If Counter = 1 Then
        For N = i1 To J1
            If SortyearArray(I) = Year(N) Then
                Selection.TypeText Text:="(" & AuthorName(N) & Year(N) & ")"
            End If
        Next N
    End If
Next I
```

Comment: Will your Array which contains "SDF", "ELS" have duplicates like the 2nd array which has duplicate years?

Comment: ELS and EFD have the same year. since EFD is the duplicate value of ELS. I need to Print it like this                                                PJK 1983, EFD 1986, ELS 1986, WKL 1995, SDF 1997.

Comment: I understand that. What I mean is will the 1st array have duplicates? i.e will there be two "SDF" in the 1st array?

Comment: Yeah. In Name (SDF) also have duplicates

Comment: So you can have items like `SDF 1997` and `SDF 2001`?

Comment: For your reference. I have a code for this in Excel Vba. But it is some what difficult to pass argument values of Arrayelements from word to excel.

Comment: If it is in Excel then that makes our job easier. Else it become slightly complex to handle two different arrays and sort them so that their sequence is not disturbed. Can you exactly mention how your data looks in Excel?

Comment: My source data having Reference name with year. it is cited in number format inside the content. so need to fetch the Reference Name and Year in two different arrays and first i sorted year information in chronological order if the year value repeats then we need to sort the name for that particular Year' Authorname.

Comment: We have two array first array value is Name and then Year.

Comment: What I mean is if the data is in 2 separate columns then we don't need two arrays. We can directly get the data from Excel. If you want you can upload a sample excel file so that I can give you an example.

Comment: Certainly. Data value a in separate column only. First Column is for name and second is for year.

Comment: Got mail from your blog. I will sent the Macro to your hotmail id.

Comment: Would recommend updating the file in wikisend.com and sharing the link here :)

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=681591 Refer this link for excel pgm.

Comment: I don't see an attachment there?

Comment: Please Refer that link(7th reply). It has the code for Sorting Chronologically and then Alphabetically and print it into word.

Comment: I have a similar code but I was waiting for you to upload the excel file :) anyways hope your query is sorted now.

Comment: Have some problem with uploading thats way. Ji, I struggle up with passing the array from word to excel. Is it possible to pass it in arguments?

Comment: Without looking at your file, I am sorry, i cannot help you any better than what is done in the VBF thread.

Comment: I will Upload my document with the code. in Filefactory.com

Comment: Please download the files from this link: Read this first:[url]http://www.filefactory.com/file/7bs7pqwfoyt3/n/Read_this_txt[/url]
Reference document:[url]http://www.filefactory.com/file/3zxq9c2gwn7x/n/New_Reference_File_doc[/url]
Macro in text:[url]http://www.filefactory.com/file/6g3feskvsht9/n/Macro_to_change_name_txt[/url]

Answer (score 2):

**The input**

```
SDF 1997
ELS 1986
PJK 1983
WKL 1995
EFD 1986
```

**Core functions:**

```
    Public Function QuickSort(ByRef array2check() As String, min As Long, max As Long) As Boolean
Dim lo As Long, hi As Long
Dim lo0 As Long, hi0 As Long
Dim midPos As String

    lo = min: hi = max
    lo0 = lo: hi0 = hi
    midPos = array2check((lo0 + hi0) / 2)
    DoEvents
    While (lo <= hi)
        While ((lo < hi0) And (array2check(lo) < midPos))
            lo = lo + 1
        Wend
        While ((hi > lo0) And (array2check(hi) > midPos))
            hi = hi - 1
        Wend
        If lo <= hi Then
            Call swap(array2check, lo, hi)
            lo = lo + 1
            hi = hi - 1
        End If
    DoEvents
    Wend

    If lo0 < hi Then Call QuickSort(array2check, lo0, hi)
    If lo < hi0 Then Call QuickSort(array2check, lo, hi0)

    QuickSort = True

End Function

Private Sub swap(arr() As String, idx1 As Long, idx2 As Long)
Dim tmp As String
    tmp = arr(idx1)
    arr(idx1) = arr(idx2)
    arr(idx2) = tmp
End Sub
```

**The Sample tester**

```
Public Sub sample_test()
    Dim test_arr() As String
    test_arr = Split("SDF 1997" & vbCrLf & "ELS 1986" & vbCrLf & "PJK 1983" & vbCrLf & "WKL 1995" & vbCrLf & "EFD 1986", vbCrLf)
    If QuickSort(test_arr, LBound(test_arr), UBound(test_arr)) = True Then
        'Debug.Print Join(test_arr, vbCrLf)
        MsgBox Join(test_arr, vbCrLf)
    End If
End Sub
```

**The Result**

```
EFD 1986
ELS 1986
PJK 1983
SDF 1997
WKL 1995
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett:If array is quite big then this would never hang the user machine.

Comment: Sure, but I've never seen such a liberal use of `DoEvents` at every turn... Especially considering that `DoEvents` itself costs time to run.

Comment: It might be a big problem during debugging in presence with an ``Timer`` control present. I think you're right. And I've updated my answer.