# Simplest way to convert a number list to a readable string in VBA

Tags: vba

Given an array of numbers:

[1,3,4,5,8,9,11]

What's the simplest way in VBA to convert that list to a readable string, e.g:

1, 3-5, 8-9, 11

I could just rewrite my VB.net function to VBA but it's already quite long winded and it will end up even longer in VBA.

```
Public Shared Function GroupedNumbers(nums As List(Of Long))

    If nums Is Nothing OrElse nums.Count = 0 Then Return "-"

    If nums.Count = 1 Then Return nums(0)

    Dim lNums = nums.Distinct().OrderBy(Function(m) m).ToList

    Dim curPos As Long = 1
    Dim lastNum As Long = lNums(0)
    Dim i As Long = 0
    Dim numStr As String = lNums(0)
    Dim isGap As Boolean = False

    Do Until i >= lNums.Count - 1
        Do Until i >= lNums.Count - 1 OrElse lNums(i) + 1 <> lNums(i + 1)
            i += 1
            isGap = True
        Loop
        If isGap Then
            numStr += "-" & lNums(i)
        End If
        If i <> lNums.Count - 1 Then
            numStr += ", " & lNums(i + 1)
            isGap = False
            i += 1
        End If
    Loop

    Return numStr

End Function
```

Just wondering if anyone has a better way of doing this before i go about rewriting it for VBA?

Comment: Are you sure about your output? what's the rule for it? or did you mean for the output to be `1-3,4,5-8,9-11`?

Comment: yes i am sure, it's not 1-3 because there is no 2.. it should only join adjacent numbers

Comment: Oh I got your point. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a simple method, you might use something like the following:

```
Function GroupedNumbers(nums() As Long) As String
    SortMe (nums) 'No built-in sort method in VBA,
                  'so you need to implement one yourself (see links below).
    Dim numStr As String
    numStr = nums(0)
    For i = 1 To UBound(nums)
        If nums(i) = nums(i - 1) + 1 Then
            numStr = numStr & IIf(nums(i) + 1 = nums(i + 1), "", "-" & nums(i))
        Else
            numStr = numStr & ", " & nums(i)
        End If
    Next i
    GroupedNumbers = numStr
End Function
```

For array sorting you might refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152319/4934172).

And if you want something more simple, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077228/4934172) which use the .NET version of `ArrayList` for sorting. Hence you would need to adapt the above function to work with `ArrayList` instead of `Array`.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That was a bit shorter than mine, but i had to make some changes to it as i was passing in a collection just for uniqueness and that fell over when i tried to test the last number against one higher.

Answer (score 0):

Well i took the long route:

```
Public Sub SortCollection(ByRef c As Collection)
Dim tmp
For i = 1 To c.Count - 1
    For j = i + 1 To c.Count
        If c(i) > c(j) Then
           vTemp = c(j)
           c.Remove j
           c.Add tmp, tmp, i
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub


Public Function NumberListGrouped(cells As Range) As String

    If cells.Count = 0 Then
        AnimalIdListGrouped = "-"
    ElseIf cells.Count = 1 Then
        AnimalIdListGrouped = cells(1, 1)
    End If

    Dim c As New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In cells
        c.Add CInt(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    SortCollection c
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim numStr As String: numStr = c(1)
    Dim isGap As Boolean: isGap = False

    Do Until i >= c.Count
        DoEvents
        Do Until i >= c.Count Or c(i) + 1 <> c(i + 1)
            i = i + 1
            isGap = True
            DoEvents
        Loop
        If isGap Then
            numStr = numStr & "-" & c(i)
        End If
        If i <> c.Count Then
            numStr = numStr & ", " & c(i + 1)
            isGap = False
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop

    NumberListGrouped = numStr

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you ever use VBA in Excel, you could have it do the work for you as follows

```
Function GroupedNumbers(nums() As Long) As String
    Dim strng As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums) - 1
        strng = strng & CStr(nums(i)) & ",A"
    Next i
    strng = "A" & strng & CStr(nums(i))
    GroupedNumbers = Replace(Replace(Replace(Intersect(Columns(1), Range(strng)).Address(False, False), ",A", ", "), "A", ""), ":", "-")
End Function
```