# Arrange excel value in alphabetical order

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Good day! I want to ask if there's a way to arrange the cell value in alphabetical order?

#### Example Column A

```
A,M
A,Q
Q,A
M,A
```

I want to alphabetically arrange the value of a single cell. Not sorting the column.

Result should be like this:

```
A,M
A,Q
A,Q
A,M
```

Comment: An approach would be loop through column A, use [split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) to split each cell by `,` which results in an array. Then sort that array and use [join function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b65z3h4h(v=vs.90).aspx) to join the array into a string and write it back into cell. If you get stuck anywhere come back and post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this VBA code, which makes use of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077228/5459839) for sorting:

```
Dim col As Variant
Dim list As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim part as Variant

' Create a list that can be used for sorting
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

' Get cell contents into an array and loop over each value
col = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1)
For i = 1 To UBound(col)
    ' Extract the comma-separated values with Split and add them to the list
    list.Clear
    For Each part In Split(col(i, 1), ",")
        list.Add part
    Next
    ' Now use the handy Sort method on that list
    list.Sort
    ' Join the result back to the comma-separated format, and put it in the array
    col(i, 1) = Join(list.ToArray(), ",")
Next
' Put the modified array contents back in the sheet where they came from
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1) = col
```