# How can I improve this sorting algorithm?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, algorithm, sorting

**What I need:**

I often need to rearrange multidimensional arrays, especially with timestamps. For that I need a routine, that results in a permanent sort order. Since the data can be huge, it has to be performant as possible.

I would like to have some feedback to my current efforts. I'm trying to understand sorting arrays practical. I'm not a programmer, if possible be patient. :)

I'll appreciate every help/tips! I'm going to learn some new things maybe.

**What my efforts are so far:**

For the beginning I took the bubble sort algorithm. It does what is needed, BUT its performance is very low. It needs more than 20 seconds for sorting a column within 582 rows and 114 columns.

The code works with single- and multi-column-arrays. I use regular expressions, so keep in mind the little function a the end of the code.

I've commented my code step by step, I hope its still readable.

I know QuickSort would be much faster, but I haven't understand to make this algorithm permanent/stable yet. I've found this solution [Sorting a multidimensionnal array in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873182/sorting-a-multidimensionnal-array-in-vba), but as said, its not permanent.

Especially for Excel I know the way to copy an array to a worksheet and to sort it there. My goal is to avoid this solution. :)

```
'++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
'+
'+  BubbleSort_Array
'+
'+  Sort algorithm: BubbleSort
'+  Sorts by: 1. numbers, 2. dates, 3. Zeichenketten (also with consecutive number, e.g. "Book1,Book2,Book3..."; Capital letters before small letters)
'+  Parameter "Data": Requires an array (VARIANT) with one or more columns and rows, by reference
'+  Paramater "Column" is a LONG, follows the counting by "Option Base 0" (first column = 0)
'+  Parameter "Direction" is an EXCEL-based constant, that determines the sortdirection (ascending/descending)
'+
'++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Public Sub BubbleSort_Array( _
        ByRef Data() As Variant, _
        Optional Column As Long = -1, _
        Optional Direction As XlSortOrder = 1 _
            )
        
        Dim InnerIndex As Long 'common variable, for the inner loop
        Dim OuterIndex As Long 'common variable, for the outer loop
        Dim SwapItem As Variant 'variable to temporarily save content, that could be swapped with another item
        Dim SwapItem2 As Variant 'variable to temporarily save content, that could be swapped with another item
        
        Dim ErrNum As Long 'variable for error number of the ERR-object
        Dim lngRow As Long 'common variable for the rows of an array
        Dim lngColumn As Long 'common variable for the column of an array
            
        Dim colNumber As New Collection 'variable to save a part of digits from an entry
        Dim colText As New Collection 'variable to save a part of text from an entry
        Dim colDates As New Collection 'variable to save dates from an entry
        
        Dim SortIndex() As Variant 'array for sorting and mapping the specified COLUMN
        Dim CopyData() As Variant 'array for the original data, but sorted
    
'Check, whether the given array is a one- or multi-column array
    
        On Error Resume Next
        
            ErrNum = UBound(Data, 2)
            ErrNum = Err.Number
            
        On Error GoTo 0
    
'If there is an error and the parameter COLUMN is still -1 the parameter DATA is an one-column-array
    
        If ErrNum > 0 And Column = -1 Then

'Outer loop

            For OuterIndex = LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)
            
'Inner loop

                For InnerIndex = LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)
                    
'Execute the following statement as long the current index is not the last one (it would throw an error 9 by trying to access the next item)
                    
                    If InnerIndex < UBound(Data) Then
        
'To differentiate between the values
'Check, whether the value and the next value are dates
        
                        If VBA.IsDate(Data(InnerIndex)) And VBA.IsDate(Data(InnerIndex + 1)) Then
                        
'Save the dates in a temporary collection
        
                            colDates.Add VBA.CDate(Data(InnerIndex)), "date1"
                            colDates.Add VBA.CDate(Data(InnerIndex + 1)), "date2"
                            
                        Else
        
'If both values are not dates, split the value in case it is a STRING with an number at the end
'like "Paper1", "Paper2" etc.
        
                            colNumber.Add RegEx_Replace(Data(InnerIndex), ".*(\d+$)", "$1"), "current"
                            colNumber.Add RegEx_Replace(Data(InnerIndex + 1), ".*(\d+$)", "$1"), "next"
                            colText.Add RegEx_Replace(Data(InnerIndex), "(.*)\d+$", "$1"), "current"
                            colText.Add RegEx_Replace(Data(InnerIndex + 1), "(.*)\d+$", "$1"), "next"
                            
                        End If
        
'Check, whether the sortdirection is ascending
        
                        If Direction = xlAscending Then

'Sort by date

                            If VBA.IsDate(Data(InnerIndex)) And VBA.IsDate(Data(InnerIndex + 1)) Then

'Check the items depending from the sortdirection

                                If VBA.CDbl(colDates("date1")) > VBA.CDbl(colDates("date2")) Then

'In case the first item is bigger then the second, swap the items

                                    SwapItem = Data(InnerIndex)
                                    Data(InnerIndex) = Data(InnerIndex + 1)
                                    Data(InnerIndex + 1) = SwapItem
                                    
                                End If

'Sort by strings with consecutive number

                            ElseIf VBA.IsNumeric(colNumber("current")) And VBA.IsNumeric(colNumber("next")) _
                                And (colText("current") = colText("next")) Then

'In case the first item is bigger then the second, swap the items

                                If colNumber("current") > colNumber("next") Then
                                
                                    SwapItem = Data(InnerIndex)
                                    Data(InnerIndex) = Data(InnerIndex + 1)
                                    Data(InnerIndex + 1) = SwapItem
                                    
                                End If
            
                            Else

'Sort by strings
'In case the first item is bigger then the second, swap the items

                                If Data(InnerIndex) > Data(InnerIndex + 1) Then
                                
                                    SwapItem = Data(InnerIndex)
                                    Data(InnerIndex) = Data(InnerIndex + 1)
                                    Data(InnerIndex + 1) = SwapItem
                                    
                                End If
                            
                            End If

'Sort descending

                        Else

'Sort descending

'Sort by date

                            If VBA.IsDate(Data(InnerIndex)) And VBA.IsDate(Data(InnerIndex + 1)) Then

                                If VBA.CDbl(colDates("date1")) < VBA.CDbl(colDates("date2")) Then
                                
'In case the first item is smaller then the second, swap the items

                                    SwapItem = Data(InnerIndex)
                                    Data(InnerIndex) = Data(InnerIndex + 1)
                                    Data(InnerIndex + 1) = SwapItem
                                    
                                End If

'Sort by strings with consecutive number

                            ElseIf VBA.IsNumeric(colNumber("current")) And VBA.IsNumeric(colNumber("next")) And _
                                (colText("current") = colText("next")) Then
            
'In case the first item is smaller then the second, swap the items

                                If colNumber("current") < colNumber("next") Then
                                
                                    SwapItem = Data(InnerIndex)
                                    Data(InnerIndex) = Data(InnerIndex + 1)
                                    Data(InnerIndex + 1) = SwapItem
                                    
                                End If
                                
                            Else

'Sort by strings
'In case the first item is smaller then the second, swap the items

                                If Data(InnerIndex) < Data(InnerIndex + 1) Then
                                
                                    SwapItem = Data(InnerIndex)
                                    Data(InnerIndex) = Data(InnerIndex + 1)
                                    Data(InnerIndex + 1) = SwapItem
                                    
                                End If
                            
                            End If
                            
                        End If
                        
                    End If
                    
                    Set colNumber = Nothing
                    Set colText = Nothing
                    Set colDates = Nothing
                    
                Next
                
            Next
        
        Else

'Resize the array SortIndex for sorting the specified COLUMN
'Needs two columns: One for the index of the original data, and one for the values to be sorted

            ReDim SortIndex(UBound(Data, 1), 1)
            
            For InnerIndex = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)

'Save index of the original data

                SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0) = InnerIndex

'Save values of the specified COLUMN

                SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1) = Data(InnerIndex, Column)
                
            Next
            
'Outer loop

            For OuterIndex = LBound(SortIndex, 1) To UBound(SortIndex, 1)

'Inner loop

                For InnerIndex = LBound(SortIndex, 1) To UBound(SortIndex, 1)

'Execute the following statement as long the current index is not the last one (it would throw an error 9 by trying to access the next item)

                    If InnerIndex < UBound(SortIndex, 1) Then

'To differentiate between the values
'Check, whether the value and the next value are dates

                        If VBA.IsDate(SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1)) And VBA.IsDate(SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1)) Then
                    
'Save the dates in a temporary collection

                            colDates.Add VBA.CDate(SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1)), "date1"
                            colDates.Add VBA.CDate(SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1)), "date2"
                            
                        Else
                        
'If both values are not dates, split the value in case it is a STRING with an number at the end
'like "Paper1", "Paper2" etc.

                            colNumber.Add RegEx_Replace(SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1), ".*(\d+$)", "$1"), "current"
                            colNumber.Add RegEx_Replace(SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1), ".*(\d+$)", "$1"), "next"
                            colText.Add RegEx_Replace(SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1), "(.*)\d+$", "$1"), "current"
                            colText.Add RegEx_Replace(SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1), "(.*)\d+$", "$1"), "next"
                            
                        End If

'Check the sortdirection

                        If Direction = xlAscending Then

'Sort by date

                            If VBA.IsDate(SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1)) And VBA.IsDate(SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1)) Then
            
                               If VBA.CDbl(colDates("date1")) > VBA.CDbl(colDates("date2")) Then

'In case the first item is bigger then the second, swap the items

                                    SwapItem = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0)
                                    SwapItem2 = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0) = SwapItem
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1) = SwapItem2
                                    
                                End If
                                
'Sort by strings with consecutive numbers

                            ElseIf VBA.IsNumeric(colNumber("current")) And VBA.IsNumeric(colNumber("next")) _
                                And (colText("current") = colText("next")) Then
                            
'In case the first item is bigger then the second, swap the items

                                If colNumber("current") > colNumber("next") Then
                                
                                    SwapItem = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0)
                                    SwapItem2 = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0) = SwapItem
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1) = SwapItem2
                                    
                                End If
            
                            Else

'Sort by strings
'In case the first item is bigger then the second, swap the items

                                If SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1) > SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1) Then
                                
                                    SwapItem = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0)
                                    SwapItem2 = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0) = SwapItem
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1) = SwapItem2
                                    
                                End If
                            
                            End If
                            
                        Else

'Sort descending
'Sort by dates

                            If VBA.IsDate(SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1)) And VBA.IsDate(SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1)) Then

'In case the first item is smaller then the second, swap the items

                               If VBA.CDbl(colDates("date1")) < VBA.CDbl(colDates("date2")) Then
                               
                                    SwapItem = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0)
                                    SwapItem2 = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0) = SwapItem
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1) = SwapItem2
                                End If
  
'Sort by strings with consecutive numbers

                            ElseIf VBA.IsNumeric(colNumber("current")) And VBA.IsNumeric(colNumber("next")) And _
                                (colText("current") = colText("next")) Then
            
'In case the first item is smaller then the second, swap the items

                                If colNumber("current") < colNumber("next") Then
                                    SwapItem = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0)
                                    SwapItem2 = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0) = SwapItem
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1) = SwapItem2
                                End If
                                
                            Else

'Sort by strings

                                If SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1) < SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1) Then

'In case the first item is smaller then the second, swap the items

                                    SwapItem = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0)
                                    SwapItem2 = SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 0) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex, 1) = SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1)
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 0) = SwapItem
                                    SortIndex(InnerIndex + 1, 1) = SwapItem2
                                    
                                End If
                            
                            End If
                            
                        End If
                        
                    End If
                    
                    Set colNumber = Nothing
                    Set colText = Nothing
                    Set colDates = Nothing
                    
                Next
            Next
    
'Resize a new array with the same size like the original DATA

            ReDim CopyData(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2))
            
'Write the data according to the array SortIndex (= sorts the whole original data)

            For lngRow = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
                
                For lngColumn = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
                
                    CopyData(lngRow, lngColumn) = Data(SortIndex(lngRow, 0), lngColumn)
                
                Next
                    
            Next
            
'Overwrite the original data with the sorted data

            For lngRow = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
                
                For lngColumn = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
                
                    Data(lngRow, lngColumn) = CopyData(lngRow, lngColumn)
                
                Next
                    
            Next
            
        End If
        
    End Sub
'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
'+
'+  RegEx_Replace
'+
'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    
    Public Function RegEx_Replace( _
        varString As Variant, _
        strSearchPattern As String, _
        strReplaceString As String, _
        Optional blnCase_Insensitive As Boolean = True, _
        Optional blnGlobalSearch As Boolean = True, _
        Optional blnMultiLine As Boolean = False _
        ) As String
        
        Dim RegEx As Object
        
        Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

        With RegEx
            .IgnoreCase = blnCase_Insensitive
            .Global = blnGlobalSearch
            .MultiLine = blnMultiLine
            .Pattern = strSearchPattern
        End With
        
        RegEx_Replace = RegEx.Replace(varString, strReplaceString)
        
    End Function
```

Comment: There are many algorithms that work better than Bubble sort (which takes O(n^2) time).

Comment: As Excel has its own sorting features, why do you want to want to write your own sorting algorithm?

Comment: If you want to do this via VBA, then I suggest you use [`ArrayList` and its `Sort` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077228/5459839)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using the "excel worksheet method".  It's pretty efficient and useful for complicated multidimensional sorting.  You can write/read the data easily to/from VBA multidimensional arrays; and do the sorting on a temporary hidden sheet which you subsequently delete.  It is both fast **and** stable.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It seems that I have a look at ArrayList, which is new to me, and I'm going to try it with the worksheet method.

Comment: @Dominique: Which sorting features do you mean?

Comment: @Rajah9: Which stable sorting algorithm would you prefer for multidimensional sorting?

Comment: @Sergeij_Molotow: check my answer, I've shown a screenshot.

Comment: In your question, you noted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873182/sorting-a-multidimensionnal-array-in-vba . This uses a quicksort algorithm. Please take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort-vs-merge-sort/ for a comparison of quicksort vs. merge sort and when you might want to use each.

Comment: @trincot I've tested ArrayList at my private pc. It's really nice. Unfortunately it requires NET Framework 3.5, even when a newer version is installed. On my companys pc I'm not allowed to install software on my own.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I've tested the worksheet method, it's powerful and fast, I'm goint to follow this way, too and will update my question soon (have to be at work), because I've a little issue with writing a single array to the sheet.

Comment: @Dominique Sorry, I can't see your answer and screenshot. Where did you answer my question? Maybe I've failed to see something. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach - broken out some of the functionality into separate methods but the main Sub has a similar signature to yours (with one additional parameter)

```vb
'run some tests
Sub Tester()

    Dim arr
    
    BubbleSort_Array Array(), 1 'empty array: does nothing
    
    arr = Array(5, 4, 1, 3, 2)
    BubbleSort_Array arr, 1
    [P1].Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
    
    '1-dimensional array
    arr = Array("1 Title", "2 Title", "10 Title", "33 Title", "16 Title", "blah")
    BubbleSort_Array arr, 1    'sort raw values
    [P2].Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
    
    arr = Array("1 Title", "2 Title", "10 Title", "33 Title", "16 Title", "blah")
    BubbleSort_Array arr, 1, "SortOnVal"  'sort on Val() transformation
    [P3].Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
    
    arr = Array("1 Title", "2 Title", "10 Title", "33 Title", "16 Title", "blah")
    BubbleSort_Array arr, 1, "SortOnVal", xlDescending 'sort on Val() transformation, descending
    [P4].Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
    
    '2-dimensional array (from A1:N22)
    arr = [A1].CurrentRegion.Value
    BubbleSort_Array arr, 3    'sort 2D array on third column ("Val1", "Val2",...."Val22")
    [A25].Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr  'sort is "ascibetical"
    
    arr = [A1].CurrentRegion.Value
    BubbleSort_Array arr, 3, "NumberOnly"   'sort 2D array on third column, after extracting a number where present
    [A49].Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr  'sort looks correct
    
End Sub

'Sort array `data` in-place, using optional column position if 2D array
'Optional `ParseFunction` parameter is the name of a single-input function to transform values prior to sorting
Sub BubbleSort_Array(ByRef data As Variant, Optional Column As Long = -1, _
                            Optional ParseFunction As String = "", _
                            Optional Direction As XlSortOrder = 1)
    
    Dim dims As Long, lbr As Long, lbc As Long, ubr As Long, ubc As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrSort, tmp, tmp2, swap As Boolean, arrOut
    
    dims = Dimensions(data)   'check input array dimensions
    Debug.Print "dims", dims
    If dims < 1 Or dims > 2 Then Exit Sub
    
    lbr = LBound(data, 1)
    ubr = UBound(data, 1)
    If dims = 1 Then data = Make2D(data) 'normalize input to 2D array (single column)
    lbc = LBound(data, 2)
    ubc = UBound(data, 2)
    If Column = -1 Then Column = lbc 'sort defaults to first column
    
    'make an array for sorting: first column is values to sort on, second is row indexes from `data`
    ' advantage is you're shuffling fewer items when sorting, and expensive transformations only run once
    ReDim arrSort(lbr To ubr, 1 To 2)
    For i = lbr To ubr
        tmp = data(i, Column) 'value to sort on
        If Len(ParseFunction) > 0 Then tmp = Application.Run(ParseFunction, tmp) 'custom transformation?
        arrSort(i, 1) = tmp
        arrSort(i, 2) = i
    Next i
    
    'now sort the array...
    For i = lbr To ubr - 1
        For j = i + 1 To ubr
            swap = IIf(Direction = xlAscending, arrSort(i, 1) > arrSort(j, 1), _
                                                arrSort(i, 1) < arrSort(j, 1))
            If swap Then
                tmp = arrSort(j, 1)         'swap positions in the "comparison" array
                tmp2 = arrSort(j, 2)
                arrSort(j, 1) = arrSort(i, 1)
                arrSort(j, 2) = arrSort(i, 2)
                arrSort(i, 1) = tmp
                arrSort(i, 2) = tmp2
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ReDim arrOut(lbr To ubr, lbc To ubc)  'size the output array
    'using the sorted array, copy data from the original array
    For i = lbr To ubr
        For j = lbc To ubc
            arrOut(i, j) = data(arrSort(i, 2), j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    If dims = 1 Then arrOut = Make1D(arrOut) 'switch back to 1D if input was 1D
    
    data = arrOut 'replace the input array in-place
End Sub

'return result of Val()
Function SortOnVal(v)
    SortOnVal = Val(v)
End Function

'extract the first *whole* number from string `v`
Function NumberOnly(v) As Long
    Dim rv, i, c
    For i = 1 To Len(v)
        c = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(c) Then
            rv = rv & c
        Else
            If Len(rv) > 0 Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If Len(rv) = 0 Then rv = 0
    NumberOnly = CLng(rv)
End Function


'----Helper functions

'find the dimension of an array
Function Dimensions(data As Variant)
    Dim d As Long, ub
    d = 1
    Do
        ub = Empty
        On Error Resume Next
        'Debug.Print d, LBound(data, d), UBound(data, d)
        ub = UBound(data, d)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ub = -1 Or IsEmpty(ub) Then Exit Do 'also checking for undimensioned case...
        d = d + 1
    Loop
    Dimensions = d - 1
End Function

'transform a 1-D array into a 2D array (single-column)
Function Make2D(arr)
    Dim i As Long, arrOut
    ReDim arrOut(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arrOut(i, 1) = arr(i)
    Next i
    Make2D = arrOut
End Function

'transform a single-column 2-D array into a 1D array
Function Make1D(arr)
    Dim i As Long, arrOut
    ReDim arrOut(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arrOut(i) = arr(i, 1)
    Next i
    Make1D = arrOut
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that there is a function to call a function based on a variables value. I've tested your code, the performance is very good, but it seems not to be stable. I've sorted a list of names and surnames and it didn't hold the first sort. :(

Comment: Why do you use this line "swap = IIf(Direction = xlAscending, arrSort(i, 1) > arrSort(j, 1), arrSort(i, 1) < arrSort(j, 1))" not in the If-statement below?

Comment: Forgot the "stable" bit - I will try to adapt it maybe using https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/k12p50/visualising_sorting_algorithms_in_vba/   `swap=...` is used to determine whether to swap the rows depending on whether the sort direction is ascending or descending.

Comment: Willimans Thanks for the link and the link.

Answer (score 1):

Weird, I thought I uploaded this screenshot yesterday:

[image]

As you see, you can check the "Data" ribbon, "Filter&Sort" choice, and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've decided to use the excel-worksheet-method. Thanks for Dominique and Ron Rosenfeld.

Beside the good performance it sorts dates and numbers right.

Here is my code:

```
'++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
'+
'+  Sort_by_Excel
'+
'+  Sort algorithm: Excel
'+  Sorts by: 1. numbers, 2. dates, 3. strings
'+  Parameter "arrData": Requires an array (VARIANT) with one or more columns and rows, by reference
'+  Parameter "wsWorksheet": a worksheet to copy and sort the data
'+  Paramater "Column" is a LONG, follows the normal counting for worksheets (first column = 1)
'+  Parameter "SortDirection" is an EXCEL-based constant, that determines the sortdirection (ascending/descending)
'+
'+  Current performance: 582 rows and 114 columns are sorted in <1 sec
'+  Works with Option Base 0 and 1
'+
'++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Public Sub Sort_by_Excel( _
    ByRef arrData As Variant, _
    wsWorksheet As Worksheet, _
    Optional Column As Long, _
    Optional SortDirection As XlSortOrder = 1 _
    )

    Dim rngKey As Range
    Dim rngSortRange As Range
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngColumn As Long
    Dim lngErrNumber As Long

'Check, whether it is a single-column array or multi-column array

    On Error Resume Next
    
    lngErrNumber = UBound(arrData, 2)
    lngErrNumber = Err.Number
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
'Code for multi-column array

    If lngErrNumber = 0 Then

'If COLUMN is not in the range of existing columns leave the sub, data is still unsorted

        If Column < LBound(arrData, 1) + 1 - LBound(arrData, 1) And Column > UBound(arrData, 2) + 1 - LBound(arrData, 2) Then Exit Sub

        With wsWorksheet

'Remove everything from the worksheet

            .Cells.Clear
            
'Define a key cell for sorting (the first cell of to be sorted column)

            Set rngKey = .Cells(1, Column)
    
'Define the range, where the data will be copied to
'Size of arrData

            Set rngSortRange = .Range( _
                .Cells(1, 1), .Cells( _
                    UBound(arrData, 1) + 1 - LBound(arrData, 1), _
                    UBound(arrData, 2) + 1 - LBound(arrData, 2)) _
                )
                
        End With
            
        With rngSortRange

'Copy the data to the range

            .Value = arrData

'Sort the range

            .CurrentRegion.Sort _
                Key1:=rngKey, _
                Order1:=SortDirection, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

'Overwrite the original data

            For lngRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        
                For lngColumn = 1 To .Columns.Count
            
                    arrData((lngRow - 1) + LBound(arrData, 1), (lngColumn - 1) + LBound(arrData, 2)) = .Cells(lngRow, lngColumn).Value
                
                Next
            
            Next
        
        End With
    
    Else

'Code for single-column array, same as above

        With wsWorksheet
            .Cells.Clear
            Set rngKey = .Cells(1, 1)
            Set rngSortRange = .Range( _
                .Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(arrData) + 1, 1) _
                )
        End With
            
        With rngSortRange

'Copy the data to range, original array has to transposed (rotate from horizontal to vertical)

            .Value = Application.Transpose(arrData)
            .CurrentRegion.Sort _
                Key1:=rngKey, _
                Order1:=SortDirection, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

'Overwrite the original data with the sorted data

            For lngRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            
                arrData((lngRow - 1) + LBound(arrData, 1)) = .Cells(lngRow, 1).Value
            
            Next
        
        End With
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```